# I am getting an nzec error on running the below python 3.6 code

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error

I am getting an nzec error when running the following code:

```
A,B=map(int,input().split())

c=[]

x=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

for i in str(A-B):

    c.append(i)

import random

d=random.choice(c)

x.remove(d)

c.insert(c.index(d),random.choice(x))

c.remove(d)

p=str()

for i in c:

    p=p+str(i)

print(int(p))
```

Could someone explain me the error?